# Skipping last duplicate with RxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Suppose we have a subject that we use to publish some events

```
subject.onNext(...)
```

the end Subscriber is subscribed trough an Observable which was created from this subject...

I wonder if we can add some logic to observable so that if it gets the same value it wont propogate it to subscribers... or someting more complex..?

Is there a possibility to create an observable from subject that executes some code before emiting value to its subscribers?

Answer (score 13):

There is a [`distinctUntilChanged`](http://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged) operator that skips a value if it was emitted more than once in a row.

If you need more general behaviour and want to skip values based on some condition, then [`filter`](http://rxmarbles.com/#filter) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: It will distict all duplicates, but i need only last one, its values are emited by scheduling http calls then parsing string to java object... if the response is cached i dont want it to emit value...

Comment: But question is more general... suppose its some different task, not distinction... is it possible to execute some logic before observable emits the value (and if necessary cancle emition)...?

Comment: filter seems what i want but i dont really know how do i keep last value somewhere (unless i implement custom observable) and how do i access it to compare with new value?

Comment: @Vach, `distinctUntilChanged` is a bit tricky to implement using `filter` because you need to keep a history of emitted items. The functional nature of `RxJava` prohibits to pass functions with side-effects to `filter` and keeping the history is definitely a side effect. I would recommend to take a look at [`OperatorDistinctUntilChanged`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OperatorDistinctUntilChanged.java) implementation to see how it's implemented using custom operator.

Comment: Already looked at that, it just passes identity (the reference), so i changed it to Object::hashcode but it didnt work... I wont be needing filter if distictUntilChanged works... trouble is that i'm creating observable from publishSubject, then i push all values to that subject and epect observable to distict changes but it wont... I think it directly sends onNext call on subject to its subscribers...

Comment: @Vach make sure your values class has properly overloaded `hashCode` and `equals` methods. There is also an [overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#distinctUntilChanged(rx.functions.Func1)) of `distinctUntilChanged` operator that takes a key selector and omits a value only if its key is equal to the key of the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Seems [distictUntilChanged](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#distinctUntilChanged()) is exactly what is necessary in this case...

Answer (score 1):

> filter seems what i want but i dont really know how do i keep last value somewhere (unless i implement custom observable) and how do i access it to compare with new value?

You could use `.buffer(2, 1).filter(...)`, so that `filter` has access to the current and to the last element.